# jquery - run effects one after another to get smooth animation

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
$('#content').fadeOut().html('').queue(function() {});
$('#content').append(jQuery(data).find("#content").clone()).html(); 
$('#content').fadeIn();
```

I want these effects to run after the previous one is done however they all happen together!!

I tried using queue but was not successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callbacks:

```
$("#content").fadeOut(400, function() {
    $('#content').append(jQuery(data).find("#content").clone()).html();
    $('#content').fadeIn();
})
```

See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) for more info.